# how to properly use redirect on NextJs 14

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

I'm developing a webPage that needs the user to log in. As it follows, I already have configured the middleware to redirect the user in case that it doesn't have the cookies:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server';

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const currentUser = request.cookies.get('session')?.value;

  const { pathname } = request.nextUrl;

  if (!currentUser && pathname !== '/auth')
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/auth', request.url));

  if (currentUser && pathname === '/auth')
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/', request.url));
}

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    '/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)',
  ]
};
```

On the auth page, I've built a server page, with a simple form with the action to authenticate:

```
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

const Page = () => {
  const authenticate = async (formData: FormData) => {
    "use server";

    try {
      const resp = await // <DB checks if user exists and returns a session>

      cookies().set('session', JSON.stringify(resp), {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
        maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24,
        path: "/",
      });

      redirect("/");
    } catch (error) {
      if (error) {
        switch (error) {
          case "CredentialsSignin":
            return "Invalid credentials.";
          default:
            return "Something went wrong.";
        }
      }
      throw error;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form action={authenticate}>
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Usuário" required />
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Senha" required />
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Page;
```

But unfortunately after the user signs in, the page doesn't redirects to the home page('/').
With debuggers and logs, I've checked that in this moment the middleware isn't getting called.

It does set the cookies, if I manually refresh the page, it does as middleware says, but the main reason for it, was to redirect the user.

I've followed the next documentation, and it does say to use redirect on server pages, but it doesn't seems to work.

Comment: I think that it may be related to this [issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/58263)